# Confusion over definition of enthalpy as $h = f(p, T)$

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, temperature

I've often seen in textbooks that enthalpy (h) is specified as $h = f(p, T)$. We further go ahead in differentiating $h$ to get-
$$
dh  = \frac{\partial h}{\partial T} dT + \frac{\partial h}{\partial p} dp  
$$

During phase change, temperature and pressure are both constant. Hence, we need a third property (mass fraction or specific volume $\nu$), to correctly specify enthalpy during any point of the phase change process.

Why do we then specify the formula as stated above, when both $P$ and $T$ fail to fix $h$ during phase change?

Comment: h(T,P) applies to a single phase.  For a phase change, h also depends on the vapor/liquid split.

Comment: Absolutely right. 
So whenever an equation makes use of h(p,T), is it implicitly meant that the fluid in a single phase is under investigation?
More specifically, I'm looking at the derivation of Joule Thompson coefficient.

Comment: Yes.  JT is single phase.